# Which is the best Twitter api library for Actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, twitter

New to the Twitter API, but need to choose between 3 different Actionscript libraries available for the Twitter API.

Has anyone used either:

- TwitterScript
- SWX Twitter
- Tweetr

What are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 0):

I recently used Tweetr. I don't know if I can recommend it. Here's why:

1) - I don't think the events are specific enough. In his example code, every OAuth event is listened to by either an OAuthComplete or OAuthFail method. The same goes for Twitter events. I would have liked for the events to have more specific details so that I could handle them better.

2) - It uses a PHP 5 proxy that requires mod-rewrite to be installed on the server. I'm running a project on an IIS machine that has an alternative to mod-rewrite, but I can't get the proxy working. However, when I tried installing it on a separate Apache machine with mod-rewrite, it still doesn't fully work. I've spent the better part of the last 6 hours trying to get working, and am now exploring alternate libraries.

3) I followed his tutorial verbatim, and although I could connect to Twitter and fetch user info, I couldn't actually change my status. I didn't need that functionality for this project, but many other people do.

I'm actually looking at using this library for Flex (http://www.coderanger.com/blog/?p=59) but from within Flash.